# How to pinch zoom an image picked from gallery

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, android-bitmap, pinchzoom

I am start to develop a editing app i can got take images from gallery to app
But i don't know how to pinch zoom it and pan 
Please anyone tell me how to do it

Comment: Learn using [this](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/blob/master/tweet-ui/src/main/java/com/twitter/sdk/android/tweetui/internal/MultiTouchImageView.java) class from twitter-kit-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a small part of my project.

```
class ZoomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val imageBound = RectF()
    private val imageMatrixArray = FloatArray(9)
    private val scaleDetector: ScaleGestureDetector

    private var scale: Float = 1f
    private var scalePoint = PointF()
    private var translateX: Float = 0f
    private var translateY: Float = 0f
    private var lastTouchX = 0f
    private var lastTouchY = 0f
    private var lastDownTouchX = 0f
    private var lastDownTouchY = 0f
    private var lastGestureX = 0f
    private var lastGestureY = 0f
    private var isScaling = false
    private var activePointerId = -1
    private var drawableHeight = -1.0
    private var drawableWidth = -1.0
    private var minBoxRectSide = 0

    init {

        scaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, object : ScaleGestureDetector
        .SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
            override fun onScaleBegin(detector: ScaleGestureDetector?): Boolean {
                isScaling = true
                return super.onScaleBegin(detector)
            }

            override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
                scale *= detector.scaleFactor
                scale = Math.min(scale, 25f)
                scale = Math.max(0.5f, scale)

                invalidate()
                return true
            }

            override fun onScaleEnd(detector: ScaleGestureDetector?) {
                super.onScaleEnd(detector)
                isScaling = false
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        //Timber.d("Image on layout : layoutChanged = $changed")
        if (changed) {
            drawable?.let {
                resetBoxRect(it, left, right, top, bottom)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resetBoxRect(it: Drawable, left: Int, right: Int, top: Int, bottom: Int) {
        //Timber.d("image coordinates $left, $top, $right, $bottom")

        drawableHeight = it.intrinsicHeight.toDouble()
        drawableWidth = it.intrinsicWidth.toDouble()

        imageMatrix.getValues(imageMatrixArray)
        imageBound.set((left + right) / 2 - imageMatrixArray[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * it.intrinsicWidth / 2,
                (bottom - top) / 2 - imageMatrixArray[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * it.intrinsicHeight / 2,
                (left + right) / 2 + imageMatrixArray[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * it.intrinsicWidth / 2,
                (bottom - top) / 2 + imageMatrixArray[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * it.intrinsicHeight / 2)

        //Timber.d("Image bound $imageBound, and $boxRect")
        minBoxRectSide = (.01f * Math.max(imageBound.bottom - imageBound.top, imageBound.right - imageBound.left)).toInt()
        scale = 1f
        translateX = 0f
        translateY = 0f

    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        scalePoint.set(w / 2.toFloat(), h / 2.toFloat())
    }

    override fun setImageDrawable(drawable: Drawable?) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable)
        drawable?.let {
            if (imageMatrixArray != null) {
                resetBoxRect(it, left, right, top, bottom)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        //Timber.d("On touch start")
        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        //Timber.d("On touch gesture sent")
        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> onActionDown(event)
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> onMoveEvent(event)
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> activePointerId = -1
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                activePointerId = -1
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> onActionUp(event)
        }
        return true
    }


    private fun onActionDown(event: MotionEvent) {
        val actionIndex = event.actionIndex
        lastDownTouchX = event.getX(actionIndex)
        lastDownTouchY = event.getY(actionIndex)

        lastTouchX = event.getX(actionIndex)
        lastTouchY = event.getY(actionIndex)
        lastGestureX = lastTouchX
        lastGestureY = lastTouchY
        activePointerId = event.getPointerId(0)

        invalidate()
    }

    private fun onMoveEvent(event: MotionEvent) {
        if (!isScaling) {
            val index = event.findPointerIndex(activePointerId)
            val dx = (event.getX(index) - lastTouchX) / scale
            val dy = (event.getY(index) - lastTouchY) / scale
            lastTouchX = event.getX(index)
            lastTouchY = event.getY(index)

            if (Math.abs(translateX + dx) < imageBound.right - imageBound.left)
                translateX += dx
            if (Math.abs(translateY + dy) < imageBound.bottom - imageBound.top)
                translateY += dy

            invalidate()

        }
    }

    private fun onActionUp(event: MotionEvent) {
        val pointerIndex = event.actionIndex
        val pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex)
        if (pointerId == activePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            val newPointerIndex = if (pointerIndex == 0) 1 else 0
            lastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex)
            lastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex)
            activePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex)
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.save()

        canvas.scale(scale, scale, scalePoint.x, scalePoint.y)
        canvas.translate(translateX, translateY)

        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas.restore()
    }
}
```

The view can be used the xml in this way :-

```
<com.myproject.app.widgets.ZoomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/abc" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be too broad to write here all the things. Basically there are lot of libraries which provide ImageView with zoom gesture.

You can see their code or use that library as well. Here are two with highest rating on github.

- https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
- https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

You just need to use their ImageView and your ImageView will have the gesture. Like

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```